Question on partials

Let $w = f(x, y, t)$ and $x$ and $y$ depending on $t$. Suppose that at some point $(x, y)$ and at some time $t$, the partial derivatives $f_x$, $f_y$, and $f_t$ are equal to $2$, $-3$, and $5$, respectively, while $\smash{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}} = 1$ and $\smash{\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}} = 2$. Find and explain the difference between $\smash{\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{\mathrm{d}t}}$ and $f_t$.

For this question, I don't understand why $\smash{\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{\mathrm{d}t}}$ and $f_t$ would be different if both $x$ and $y$ depend on $t$. My understanding is that both should be the same. Why is this the case?

$f_t$ is the derivative w r t the third argument of $f$

right but if x and y are both functions of t, then that should equal the total derivative here.

I'd say refer to my previous answer - but that would need to be expanded with the "chain rule tree:" see here: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/ChainRule_Files/image001.png

When we write $f(x,y,t)$, we mean that $f$ is a function of 3 independent variables, and expressions like $f_t$ refer to the derivative of $f$ with respect to $t$, with $x$ and $y$ held constant. Technically, it doesn't make sense to say that "$x$ and $y$ are functions of $t$".
To make sense of your question, we should introduce two functions $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$, and define $w(t) = f(X(t), Y(t), t)$, which is a function of one variable $t$. The question is asking for the distinction between $f_t$ and $dw/dt$.
See also this previous answer of mine on an earlier question with a similar partial derivative notation confusion.
